# Scanf() function with strings

Tags: c, scanf

I have the following string to read from a scanf function

1041657W 324944N Riverside

If I call scanf():

```
    uint32_t N = 0;
    char Ch = 'z';
    char Name[100];
    scanf("%d %c %s", &N, &Ch, Name);
```

The value of the variables will be as follows

```
    N = 1041657
    Ch = 'W'
    Name = "324944N"
```

I am not sure how these values are scanned. Can you please tell me how each variable displays the given values?

Comment: you are calling printf, not scanf...?

Comment: you're right, editted

Comment: `%d` reads a number (stopping at `W`), `%c` reads a character (`W`), `%s` reads a string (stopping at whitespace).

Comment: @hmm - No, it doesn't! `printf` doesn't read anything.

Comment: @hmm yeah its a typo, thanks for that. I meant for all of it to be scanned from the given string.

Comment: I just editted again, this is what I really want. @hmm does your explanation still work?

Comment: I'm out of here - party in Thailand (all welcome).

Comment: The question was intended to use scanf(); however, it is perfectly valid as is (using printf()). There are two key
observations you needed to make:
 printf() cannot change the values stored in any of the variables
 since Name[] was not initialized, there is no guarantee of its specific contents

Comment: @JDog1999 OK, now your question looks OK, but then I didn't get your last comment mentioning `printf`. BTW hmm's comment answers the question.

Comment: @Jabberwocky ignoring my comment, haha, does hmm's explanation above make sense? I am confused on what the char Ch = 'z' and char Name[100] does.

Comment: @JDog1999 you need to start reading your beginner's C text book. _" I am confused on what the char Ch = 'z' and char Name[100] does"_: this is most basic C knowledge.`char Ch = 'z';` declares a char variable and initializes it with the ASCII value of the letter z. `char Name[100];` declares an array of 100 chars.

Comment: @Jabberwocky thanks for the explanation - why does %s stop reading at a white space? I thought strings in c are allowed to contain spaces.

Comment: @JDog1999, yes, of course string can contain spaces, but spaces are treated as delimiter with the `%s` specifier. Read the `scanf` specification.

Comment: @JDog1999 "why does %s stop reading at a white space?" --that is its design - to scan a sequence of non-space characters - not to scan a C _string_.   "I thought strings in c are allowed to contain spaces."  Yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
[wally@localhost tmp]$ cat lat.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char    name [500], dir1, dir2;
    int lng, lat, sts;

    sts = sscanf ("1041657W 324944N Riverside", "%d%c %d%c %s",
                   &lng, &dir1, &lat, &dir2, name);
    printf ("status %d, %d%c %d%c %s\n", sts, lng, dir1, lat, dir2, name);
    return 0;
}

[wally@localhost tmp]$ gcc lat.c -o lat
[wally@localhost tmp]$ ./lat 
status 5, 1041657W 324944N Riverside
```

*scanf()* returns the number of formatted arguments processed, so five means all of them were processed.

Note that for most geographic computations, DMS (degree minutes seconds) is not particularly convenient.  To convert to decimal degrees, the minutes and seconds are converted to 1/60 and 1/3600 from the 1/100 and 1/10000 converted decimal value.